# How to deep compare 2 ruby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a way to compare 2 rails object and find the difference.

Ex.

```
class User
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :college
end

class Book 
 belongs_to :user
end 

class College
  has_many :users
end
```

How do I deep compare two user objects and find the differences also the changes in the associated objects

Now suppose I have 2 instances of user object

user1 = User.first  ==> {id: 1, name: 'first last', age: 22}

user1 has 2 books with name book1 and book2 and belongs to college C1 {name: 'pqr'}

now I have another instance user2 which is a modified version of user1,

Now user2 is => {id: 2, name: 'first last1', age: 23} and user2 object has only one book book1 ( book2 is deleted from association ). And college C1 name is changed to {name: 'pqw'}

Comment: What do you mean by "rails object"? What sorts of differences? What does your example mean? What does "deep compare" mean? "Also the changes"? You probably need to work on your question.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Your `User` model doesn't have a unique constraint on `id`? How do you distinguish between `user1` that has `id: 1` and `user2` that also has `id: 1`? What do you imagine the result of this 'deep compare' to be? A boolean? A hash? Something else?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Expecting to see the difference between the 2 object, maybe a hash {name: "first last1", books: {1: {status: deleted}}, college: {name: 'pqw' }}  for only the things that are different

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord#==` just checks that `self` and the other object are instances of the same class and have the same `id`. If you want to compare their attributes and associations you need to write a custom method yourself.

Something like this might work:

```
# in models/application_record.rb
def attributes_eq?(other)
  self == other && attributes == other.attributes
end

# in models/user.rb
def attributes_eq?(other)
  super &&
    college.attributes_eq?(other.college) &&
    books_ids == other.book_ids &&
    books.zip(other.books).all? { |a, b| a.attributes_eq?(b) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize both objects using Marshal.dump

````
def deep_equals(a, b)
  Marshal.dump(a) == Marshal.dump(b)
end```
````

Answer (score -1):

Define your own == method in User and define your custom logic.

```
def ==(obj)
  #check all attributes or whatever you want to compare, if at somepoint you find a false checking attrs, return false, otherwise return true.
end
```